# How to deploy a data-driven firebase backend & angularjs app to amazon ec2 ubuntu?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-ec2, firebase, ubuntu-14.04

I have created a data-driven app with firebase backend and angular.js frontend. However, I am having trouble deploying it to my amazon ec2 ubuntu instance.

I have a t2.micro instance with AWS, I have installed apache2, node.js and npm. And I have confirmed that node.js is running on the instance.

I uploaded the html and js files to var/www/html, but when i try to run the app, it gives me a whole bunch of 404 errors (see console errors below). The 404 errors relate to the angularjs library.

"http://ec2-52-64-81-25.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com/ClippableAngularJS/js/lib/angular/angular-animate.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Does anyone know why this is happening and what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: You have a lot of technologies combined in here, which makes it impossible for me to troubleshoot unless I can sit at your machine. Some steps you might take to troubleshoot are the best I can do. A Firebase application using AngularJS is essentially just a static web site from an ec2 perspective. Can you successfully deploy a non-Firebase website? If so, you know the Firebase part is not the problem. Next step: can you deploy a non-AngularJS web site? If so, you know AngularJS is not your problem. Repeat these steps until you've found the culprit.